# Using savepoints to wrap test data in website?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have a php/MySQL system that uses transactions in the code. Therefore I cannot use transactions to create and delete test-data because you cannot do a transactions inside a transaction. I have looked at using Savepoints to achieve this, but I cannot find good examples of using both savepoints and transactions. Will you share you thoughts and samples? Kind regards Lars Nielsen

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/savepoint.html

Comment: Thanks, I have read that.
It says : "...All savepoints of the current transaction are deleted if you execute a COMMIT, or a ROLLBACK that does not name a savepoint..."

So how du I use a savepoint in my COMMIT's?

Comment: You can't commit a savepoint explicitly. What you would do is to rollback to the desired savepoint and then do a regular commit.

Comment: So the data I create in my automated test cannot be deleted or rolled back if I use transactions in different atomic operations in my application!? :-/

Then I have to create code to track and delete test-data.

Comment: You should use a dedicated testing environment where it doesn't matter what data is in the database.

Comment: I have a dedicated testing environment. My changes are not critical. But I have a rather large database which takes long time to restore.
I would like to be able to roll back my test-data so I can run the test multiple times.